# Invocation of JSF 2.0 binding methods during a specific phase of the lifecycle

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have the following situation:

```
    form1.xhtml:
    <h:commandButton action="#{bean1.action1}" /> <!-- action1 returns "form2" -->
    form2.xhtml:
    <h:form binding="#{bean2.init}">
    ...
    <h:commandButton action="#{bean2.action2}" /> <!-- *** -->
    </h:form>

    Bean2.java:
    @Named
    Bean2{
    public Object getInit(){
        return null;
    }

    public void setInit (Object i){
        //do something
    }
```

When *form1* is submitted, the binding method setInit() is executed during phase 6 RENDER_RESPONSE (after action1() returned "form2") and form2 is shown.

When *form2* is submitted, setInit() is executed during phase 1 RESTORE_VIEW if action2() returns "null". But if action2() returns "form2" instead of null, the method gets invoked **also** during phase 6.

Do you know why? Is it possible to have the binding method invoked also if the action returns null?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This makes no sense. You're clearly going the wrong direction as to solving the particular functional requirement. In order to explain you the right solution, you have to elaborate the particular functional requirement in detail.

Comment: hi, I understand what you mean.. Unfortunately I am just migrating an old JSF 1 application (which runs on WebSphere) to JSF 2.0 + JBoss. I don't really know why they did what they did and how things could work which with JSF 2 don't work.. This is one of these..